# Lodash: Filter array of objects and check if not null

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I just started using lodash and have this array of objects, where one of the properties either has an integer or is null. I know how to filter the array for items that are null, but how do I check if it's not null?

Let's say I have something like this:

```
var users = [
    { 'user': 'barney', 'default': 1 },
    { 'user': 'dino', 'default': 0 },
    { 'user': 'wilma', 'default': 1 },
    { 'user': 'fred',   'default': null }
];
```

And then I want something like:

```
var notNullDefault = _.filter(sourceData, ['is_default', ! null ]); // objects with names barney, dino, wilma
var nullDefault = _.filter(sourceData, ['is_default', null ]); // object with name fred
```

Again, I'm new to lodash, so maybe there's a better way to accomplish this too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This can be solved with [`_.reject`](https://lodash.com/docs#reject) and [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter):

```
var notNullDefault = _.reject(sourceData, ['default', null]);

var nullDefault = _.filter(sourceData, ['default', null]);
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kswf83ch)**</kbd>

Comment: Perfect. Was looking for the parallel for Angular's `$filter('filter')(collection, { 'default': '!someValue' })`.

Comment: if you are looking for records which don't have default key you can use following `var notHavingDefault = _.filter(sourceData, function(item) { return _.isUndefined(item.default) });`

Answer (score 2):

You could create a couple of predicate functions that check for default and not default users:

```
var isDefaultUser = function(user){
    return _.isNull(user.default);
}

var isNotdefaultUser = _.negate(isDefaultUser);
```

They could then be used for filtering etc.

```
var defaultUser = _.filter(users, isDefaultUser);

var notDefaultUsers = _.filter(users, isNotdefaultUser);

// partition will be an array; first element contains the default users
// second element contains the non default users 
var parition = _.partition(users, isDefaultUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with something like this:

```
var notNullDefault = _.filter(users, function(elem) { return elem.default !== null; }); 
var nullDefault = _.filter(users, function(elem) { return o.default === null; }); // object with  name fred
```

The returned array contains only the elements for which the callback function returns `true`.

Or, as they put it in [the fine manual](https://lodash.com/docs#filter): *Iterates over elements of collection, returning an array of all elements predicate returns truthy for. The predicate is invoked with three arguments: (value, index|key, collection).*

Comment: You might want to note that you're treating `null` and `undefined` as equivalent here.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let items = [1, 2, 4, null];

let isHaveNull = _.some(items, (item) => _.isNull(item));

console.log(isHaveNull);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe these libraries are sometimes just waste of time. Instead of learning a library dependent specific abstract it's best to get a good hold of ES6 array functions along with arrows. So here you go;

```js
var users = [
             { 'user': 'barney', 'default': 1 },
             { 'user': 'dino',   'default': 0 },
             { 'user': 'wilma',  'default': 1 },
             { 'user': 'fred',   'default': null }
            ],
 userNull = [],
 userFull = [];
users.forEach(e => e.default == void 0 ? userNull.push(e) : userFull.push(e));

document.write("<pre> userNull:\n" + JSON.stringify(userNull, null, 2) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre> userFull:\n" + JSON.stringify(userFull, null, 2) + "</pre>");
```